# How to run spark-submit in virtualenv for pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-submit

Is there a way to run `spark-submit` (spark v2.3.2 from HDP 3.1.0) while in a virtualenv? Have situation where have python file that uses python3 (and some specific libs) in a virtualenv (to isolate lib versions from rest of system). I would like to run this file with `/bin/spark-submit`, but attempting to do so I get...

```sh
[me@airflowetl tests]$ source ../venv/bin/activate; /bin/spark-submit sparksubmit.test.py 
  File "/bin/hdp-select", line 255
    print "ERROR: Invalid package - " + name
                                    ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("ERROR: Invalid package - " + name)?
ls: cannot access /usr/hdp//hadoop/lib: No such file or directory
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: hdp.version is not set while running Spark under HDP, please set through HDP_VERSION in spark-env.sh or add a java-opts file in conf with -Dhdp.version=xxx
    at org.apache.spark.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:118)
```

also tried...

```
(venv) [me@airflowetl tests]$ export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop/conf; spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster sparksubmit.test.py 
19/12/12 13:50:20 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
19/12/12 13:50:20 WARN shortcircuit.DomainSocketFactory: The short-circuit local reads feature cannot be used because libhadoop cannot be loaded.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/api/client/config/ClientConfig
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.TimelineClient.createTimelineClient(TimelineClient.java:55)
    ....
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig
```

## ...or (from here https://www.hackingnote.com/en/spark/trouble-shooting/NoClassDefFoundError-ClientConfig)...

```
(venv) [airflow@airflowetl tests]$ spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client --conf spark.hadoop.yarn.timeline-service.enabled=false sparksubmit.test.py 
19/12/12 15:22:48 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
19/12/12 15:22:49 INFO spark.SparkContext: Running Spark version 2.4.4
19/12/12 15:22:49 INFO spark.SparkContext: Submitted application: hph_etl_TEST
19/12/12 15:22:49 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: airflow
19/12/12 15:22:49 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: airflow
19/12/12 15:22:49 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
19/12/12 15:22:49 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
19/12/12 15:22:49 INFO spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(airflow); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(airflow); groups with modify permissions: Set()
19/12/12 15:22:49 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 45232.
19/12/12 15:22:50 INFO spark.SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
19/12/12 15:22:50 INFO spark.SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
19/12/12 15:22:50 INFO storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Using org.apache.spark.storage.DefaultTopologyMapper for getting topology information
19/12/12 15:22:50 INFO storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: BlockManagerMasterEndpoint up
19/12/12 15:22:50 INFO storage.DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/blockmgr-320366b6-609a-497b-ac40-119d11682044
19/12/12 15:22:50 INFO memory.MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 366.3 MB
19/12/12 15:22:50 INFO spark.SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
19/12/12 15:22:50 INFO util.log: Logging initialized @2663ms
19/12/12 15:22:50 INFO server.Server: jetty-9.3.z-SNAPSHOT, build timestamp: unknown, git hash: unknown
19/12/12 15:22:50 INFO server.Server: Started @2763ms
19/12/12 15:22:50 INFO server.AbstractConnector: Started ServerConnector@50a3c656{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4040}
19/12/12 15:22:50 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
19/12/12 15:22:50 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@306c15f1{/jobs,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
19/12/12 15:22:50 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@2b566f8d{/jobs/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
19/12/12 15:22:50 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@1b5ef515{/jobs/job,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
19/12/12 15:22:50 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@59f7a5e2{/jobs/job/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
19/12/12 15:22:50 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@41c58356{/stages,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
19/12/12 15:22:50 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@2d5f2026{/stages/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
19/12/12 15:22:50 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@324ca89a{/stages/stage,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
19/12/12 15:22:50 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@6f487c61{/stages/stage/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
19/12/12 15:22:50 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@3897116a{/stages/pool,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
19/12/12 15:22:50 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@68ab090f{/stages/pool/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
19/12/12 15:22:50 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@42ea3278{/storage,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
19/12/12 15:22:50 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@6eedf530{/storage/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
19/12/12 15:22:50 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@6e71a5c6{/storage/rdd,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
19/12/12 15:22:50 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@5e222a76{/storage/rdd/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
19/12/12 15:22:50 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@4dc8aa38{/environment,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
19/12/12 15:22:50 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@4c8d82c4{/environment/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
19/12/12 15:22:50 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@2fb15106{/executors,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
19/12/12 15:22:50 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@608faf1c{/executors/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
19/12/12 15:22:50 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@689e405f{/executors/threadDump,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
19/12/12 15:22:50 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@48a5742a{/executors/threadDump/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
19/12/12 15:22:50 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@6db93559{/static,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
19/12/12 15:22:50 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@4d7ed508{/,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
19/12/12 15:22:50 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@5510f12d{/api,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
19/12/12 15:22:50 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@6d87de7{/jobs/job/kill,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
19/12/12 15:22:50 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@62595660{/stages/stage/kill,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
19/12/12 15:22:50 INFO ui.SparkUI: Bound SparkUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://airflowetl.local:4040
19/12/12 15:22:51 WARN shortcircuit.DomainSocketFactory: The short-circuit local reads feature cannot be used because libhadoop cannot be loaded.
19/12/12 15:22:51 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at hw001.local/172.18.4.46:8050
19/12/12 15:22:51 INFO yarn.Client: Requesting a new application from cluster with 4 NodeManagers
19/12/12 15:22:51 INFO yarn.Client: Verifying our application has not requested more than the maximum memory capability of the cluster (15360 MB per container)
19/12/12 15:22:51 INFO yarn.Client: Will allocate AM container, with 896 MB memory including 384 MB overhead
19/12/12 15:22:51 INFO yarn.Client: Setting up container launch context for our AM
19/12/12 15:22:51 INFO yarn.Client: Setting up the launch environment for our AM container
19/12/12 15:22:51 INFO yarn.Client: Preparing resources for our AM container
19/12/12 15:22:51 WARN yarn.Client: Neither spark.yarn.jars nor spark.yarn.archive is set, falling back to uploading libraries under SPARK_HOME.
19/12/12 15:22:53 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/tmp/spark-4e600acd-2d34-4271-b01c-25f312906f93/__spark_libs__8368679994314392346.zip -> hdfs://hw001.local:8020/user/airflow/.sparkStaging/application_1572898343646_0029/__spark_libs__8368679994314392346.zip
19/12/12 15:22:54 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/home/airflow/projects/hph_etl_airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/pyspark.zip -> hdfs://hw001.local:8020/user/airflow/.sparkStaging/application_1572898343646_0029/pyspark.zip
19/12/12 15:22:55 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/home/airflow/projects/hph_etl_airflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip -> hdfs://hw001.local:8020/user/airflow/.sparkStaging/application_1572898343646_0029/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip
19/12/12 15:22:55 INFO yarn.Client: Uploading resource file:/tmp/spark-4e600acd-2d34-4271-b01c-25f312906f93/__spark_conf__5403285055443058510.zip -> hdfs://hw001.local:8020/user/airflow/.sparkStaging/application_1572898343646_0029/__spark_conf__.zip
19/12/12 15:22:55 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: airflow
19/12/12 15:22:55 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: airflow
19/12/12 15:22:55 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
19/12/12 15:22:55 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
19/12/12 15:22:55 INFO spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(airflow); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(airflow); groups with modify permissions: Set()
19/12/12 15:22:56 INFO yarn.Client: Submitting application application_1572898343646_0029 to ResourceManager
19/12/12 15:22:56 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1572898343646_0029
19/12/12 15:22:56 INFO cluster.SchedulerExtensionServices: Starting Yarn extension services with app application_1572898343646_0029 and attemptId None
19/12/12 15:22:57 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1572898343646_0029 (state: ACCEPTED)
19/12/12 15:22:57 INFO yarn.Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: AM container is launched, waiting for AM container to Register with RM
     ApplicationMaster host: N/A
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
     queue: default
     start time: 1576200176385
     final status: UNDEFINED
     tracking URL: http://hw001.local:8088/proxy/application_1572898343646_0029/
     user: airflow
19/12/12 15:22:58 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1572898343646_0029 (state: FAILED)
19/12/12 15:22:58 INFO yarn.Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: Application application_1572898343646_0029 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1572898343646_0029_000002 exited with  exitCode: 1
Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: [2019-12-12 15:22:58.214]Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_e02_1572898343646_0029_02_000001
Exit code: 1

[2019-12-12 15:22:58.215]Container exited with a non-zero exit code 1. Error file: prelaunch.err.
Last 4096 bytes of prelaunch.err :
/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/airflow/appcache/application_1572898343646_0029/container_e02_1572898343646_0029_02_000001/launch_container.sh: line 38: $PWD:$PWD/__spark_conf__:$PWD/__spark_libs__/*:$HADOOP_CONF_DIR:/usr/hdp/3.1.0.0-78/hadoop/*:/usr/hdp/3.1.0.0-78/hadoop/lib/*:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-hdfs-client/*:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-hdfs-client/lib/*:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-yarn-client/*:/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-yarn-client/lib/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:$PWD/mr-framework/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/*:/usr/hdp/${hdp.version}/hadoop/lib/hadoop-lzo-0.6.0.${hdp.version}.jar:/etc/hadoop/conf/secure:$PWD/__spark_conf__/__hadoop_conf__: bad substitution
....
```

Not sure what to make of this or how to proceed further and did not totally understand the error message after googling it.

Anyone with more experience have any further debugging tips for this or fixes?

Comment: The solution I ended up using was running `export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/path/to/my/virtualenv/bin/python` before running `spark-submit`, so command looks like... `PYSPARK_PYTHON=/path/to/my/virtualenv/bin/python; /bin/spark-submit myscript.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

spark-submit is a bash script, and uses Java classes to run, so using a virtualenv wouldn't necessarily help (although, you can see in the logs that files were uploaded from the environment).

The first error is because hdp-select requires Python2, but it looks like it ran with Python3 (probably due to your venv)

If you want to carry your Python environment to the executors and driver, you'd probably want to use the `--pyfiles` option instead, or setup the same python environment on each Spark node

Also, you seem to have Spark 2.4.4, not 2.3.2, like you say, which could explain the NoClassDef if you're mixing Spark versions (in particular pyspark from pip doesn't download any scheduler specific packages, like the YARN timeline)

But you ran the code fine and you can find the real exception under

http://hw001.local:8088/proxy/application_1572898343646_0029

Comment: Small bit to clear some confusion: `/bin/spark-submit` is the local binary (v2.3.2), `spark-sumbit` in the virtualenv references the virtualenv interpreter's installed `pyspark` (v2.4.4) (not the system one). Was just trying a buch a different things trying to get it to work.

Comment: I didn't think pyspark installed the submit script, but maybe that changed. In any case, the HDP one is customized, so it's not exactly the same as the one you'd get from straight Spark download (or pyspark)

Comment: The solution I ended up using was running `export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/path/to/my/virtualenv/bin/python` before running `spark-submit`, so command looks like... `PYSPARK_PYTHON=/path/to/my/virtualenv/bin/python; /bin/spark-submit myscript.py`