# How do I use the portable runner and spark-submit to submit beams wordcount python example to a remote spark cluster on EMR running yarn?

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, apache-beam, amazon-emr

I am trying to submit beams wordcount python example to a remote spark cluster on emr running yarn as its resource manager. According to the spark documentation this needs to be done using the [portable runner](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/spark/).

Following the portable runner instructions, I have started the job service endpoint, and it appears to start correctly::

```
$ docker run --net=host apache/beam_spark_job_server:latest --spark-master-url=spark://*.***.***.***:7077
20/08/31 12:13:08 INFO org.apache.beam.runners.jobsubmission.JobServerDriver: ArtifactStagingService started on localhost:8098
20/08/31 12:13:08 INFO org.apache.beam.runners.jobsubmission.JobServerDriver: Java ExpansionService started on localhost:8097
20/08/31 12:13:08 INFO org.apache.beam.runners.jobsubmission.JobServerDriver: JobService started on localhost:8099
20/08/31 12:13:08 INFO org.apache.beam.runners.jobsubmission.JobServerDriver: Job server now running, terminate with Ctrl+C
```

Now I try to submit the job using spark-submit, input is a plain text version of Sherlock Holmes:

```
$ spark-submit --master=yarn --deploy-mode=cluster  wordcount.py --input data/sherlock.txt --output output --runner=PortableRunner --job_endpoint=localhost:8099 --environment_type=DOCKER --environment_config=apachebeam/python3.7_sdk
20/08/31 12:19:39 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
20/08/31 12:19:40 INFO RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at ip-***-**-**-***.ec2.internal/***.**.**.***:8032
20/08/31 12:19:40 INFO Client: Requesting a new application from cluster with 2 NodeManagers
20/08/31 12:19:40 INFO Configuration: resource-types.xml not found
20/08/31 12:19:40 INFO ResourceUtils: Unable to find 'resource-types.xml'.
20/08/31 12:19:40 INFO Client: Verifying our application has not requested more than the maximum memory capability of the cluster (6144 MB per container)
20/08/31 12:19:40 INFO Client: Will allocate AM container, with 2432 MB memory including 384 MB overhead
20/08/31 12:19:40 INFO Client: Setting up container launch context for our AM
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: /usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip not found; cannot run pyspark application in YARN mode.
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:281)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.$anonfun$findPySparkArchives$2(Client.scala:1167)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.findPySparkArchives(Client.scala:1163)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.createContainerLaunchContext(Client.scala:858)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.submitApplication(Client.scala:178)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:1134)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.YarnClusterApplication.start(Client.scala:1526)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:853)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:184)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:928)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:937)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
20/08/31 12:19:40 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
20/08/31 12:19:40 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /tmp/spark-ee751413-e29d-4b1f-8a16-fb8650b1ca10
```

It appears to want pyspark to be installed, I am fairly new to submitting beam jobs to a spark cluster, is there a reason why pyspark would need to be installed when submitting a beam job? I have a feeling my spark-submit command is wrong, but I am having a hard time finding any more concrete documentation on how to do what I am trying to do.

Comment: Probably related to this thread, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59313983/how-to-run-spark-submit-in-virtualenv-for-pyspark

Comment: Maybe this one too, https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/How-to-run-spark-submit-in-virtualenv-for-pyspark/td-p/285519